# Structures saved every second index value in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm writing a project and have stumbled upon a problem.

My part has to take the entries and save them as a structure into the file. Everything seems to work properly until I try to save them. That's my `get_db_entry` code:

```
printf("Please enter a forename: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(st[index].forename, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
printf("Please enter a surname: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(st[index].surname, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
printf("Please enter an address: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(st[index].address, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
printf("Please enter plate number: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(st[index].plate_number, STRING_SIZE, stdin);
printf("Please enter account balance: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", &st[index].balance);
```

And saving looks like this:

```
void save_db(struct customer *st){
FILE *pFile;
int file_nof=0;
FILE *pnof;
pnof=fopen("nof_db.dat", "rb");
fread(&file_nof, sizeof(int), 1, pnof);
fclose(pnof);
printf("File_nof value: %d\n", file_nof);
fflush(stdin);
if((pFile = fopen("database.dat", "ab")) != NULL) // Open file in write/update mode
{
    fwrite(st, file_nof*sizeof(struct customer), 1, pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
else
{
    printf("Cannot open file");
    exit(1);
}}
```

I've checked numerous times and the index value is being passed on correctly, meaning that it counts 0,1,2,etc.

The entries are being saved for 0,2,4,6, so there is literally a padding by an empty structure every entry, say: `index=0` always saves properly, then `index=1` - empty, though the program saves into `index=2` automatically.

This leaves me with empty spaces and a waste of space.

There are multiple checks along the way that check the value of "index", so I've no idea what's going on.

PS.

```
file_nof = nof_entries = index+1
```

Comment: `fflush` is an output operation. `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Think a little bit about what the second argument to [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) really is. Hint: It's *not* a position.

Comment: It's a bad idea to save the user input into the structure immediately. What if the user types some bad input? Now that is a part of the structure. That's why you should have a temporary buffer into which you load the input. Then, if and only if the input is valid, you copy that into the structure

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  the C standard specifically states that `fflush()` is only for output streams.  The visual studio has strayed from the standard by allowing `fflush()` on input streams.  However, that is not portable and the C standard states that using `fflush` on input streams is undefined behavior

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen failed" );` then your error message and the text reason the OS thinks the function failed will be properly output to `stdout`.

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(st, file_nof*sizeof(struct customer), 1, pFile);`  this is nonsense.  Suggest: `if ( fwrite(st, sizeof(struct customer), 1, pFile) != 1) { perror( "fwrite failed" ); }

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to open-write-close a file for each item written to the file.  Much better to only open once and when all done writing, then close

Comment: regarding: `printf("Cannot open file");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`,  Strongly suggest using `perror()` as that will output your error message AND the text reason the OS thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: Please read and understand the MAN page for each function you use (after a while, you will know the syntax for the functions you normally use so will not have to look them up.